# Android audio recording with clipping distortion

Tags: android, audio, recording, clipping

I am new to Android . I want to record some audio , and then I created an Android app . It works .
But the audio it recorded is too loud , and easy to produce clipping distortion .

For example , first I start my app and speak 'hello' to my Android phone , I get the recording file 'recording1.pcm' ; then I start another recording app from GooglePlay , speak 'hello' to my Android phone at the same volume , I get the recording file 'recording2.pcm' .

then I open those two files in Audition , the waveform of 'recording1.pcm' (records by my app) is clipped , and the waveform of 'recording2.pcm' (records by another app) is not clipped . (I am sorry I cannot embed images )

the core code of recordings as follows :

```
private class RecordAudio extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            isRecording = true;
            try {
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(recordingFile)));
                int bufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(frequency, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding);
                AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER, frequency, channelConfiguration, audioEncoding, bufferSize);
                short[] buffer = new short[bufferSize * 99];
                audioRecord.startRecording();

                int r = 0;
                while (isRecording) {
                    int bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    for (int i = 0; i < bufferReadResult; i++) {
                        dos.writeShort(buffer[i]);
                    }

                    publishProgress(new Integer(r));
                    r++;
                }

                audioRecord.stop();
                dos.close();

            } catch (Throwable t) {
                Log.e("AudioRecord", "Recording Failed");
            }
            return null;
        }

    }
```

Other parameters in my app:

```
frequency = 16000;
channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_STEREO;
audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
```

I have tried the following :

1. I change the code `dos.writeShort(buffer[i]);` to `dos.writeShort(buffer[i]/2);` , then the amplitude of the waveform become half of the past , but still with clipping distortion . I think that before the buffer got the audio data , the data has been clipped .
2. I look through the API of 'audioRecord' , but no API for microphone volume .

Thanks for your help !

Comment: maybe the problem is not the volume, what happen if you record a very weak sound? does it get clipped too?

Comment: If I record a very weak sound , it won't clipped .
The problem of my app is "easy to produce clipping distortion when the sound is a little loud"